# 2.5d Aiming works in right direction but not left direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

this is my first post on StackOverflow so im sorry if im asking the question in the wrong place or anything like that. Ive followed the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q56quIB2sOg and done the second part called "Weapon Ik". Im making a 2.5d game, my character aims correctly and moves the upper spine correctly when facing the right, but when facing the left the character starts freaking out.
[Works in right direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRjDY.png), [does not work when facing left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wSHe.png). I rotate my player with a simple script that sets the y rotation to 180. Here is my code for the Weapon Ik script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

public class WeaponIK1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Vector3 targetVector;
    [SerializeField] Transform aimTransform;
    [SerializeField] Transform spine2;

    [SerializeField] int iterations = 10;
    public float angleLimit = 90;
    public float distanceLimit = 1.5f;
    void Update()
    {
        targetVector = ShootPortal.mousePosition;
        targetVector = new Vector3(0, targetVector.y, targetVector.z);
        //Debug.Log(targetTransform);
    }
    Vector3 GetTargetPosition()
    {
        Vector3 targetDirection = targetVector - aimTransform.position;
        Vector3 aimDirection = aimTransform.forward;
        float blendOut = 0;
        float targetAngle = Vector3.Angle(targetDirection, aimDirection);
        if (targetAngle > angleLimit)
        {
            blendOut += (targetAngle - angleLimit) / 50;
        }

        Vector3 direction = Vector3.Slerp(targetDirection, aimDirection, blendOut);
        return aimTransform.position + direction;
    }
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = GetTargetPosition();
        //Debug.Log("GetTargetPosition: " + GetTargetPosition());
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            AimAtTarget(spine2, targetPosition);
        }
    }

    void AimAtTarget(Transform bone, Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        Vector3 aimDirection = aimTransform.forward;
        Debug.Log(aimTransform.forward);
        Vector3 targetDirection = targetPosition - aimTransform.position;
        Quaternion aimTowards = Quaternion.FromToRotation(aimDirection, targetDirection);
        //Debug.Log("aimTowards: " + aimTowards);
        bone.rotation = bone.rotation * aimTowards;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright i fixed it, the issue was that when i was turning the player to the left i would set the player.rotation to a Quaternion.Euler. If i instead use player.Rotate(0, 180, 0) it all works.